# How to I deal with slowness from linked servers and remote queries?

Tags: sql-server

**Machine 1**

Application Data Warehouse

SQL Server 2012, Basically Read Only Access

**Machine 2**

Custom Data Warehouse

SQL Server 2012, Full Access

**Problem**

I am trying to move some queries from Machine 1 to Machine 2.  The queries are still referencing DBs on Machine 1 using linked servers.

1)  Some queries are MUCH slower (like 20x slower) in the new environment.  I think it has to do with joining temp tables (which are local) to remote tables (through linked servers).

2)  I can't seem to use remote functions directly, I have to create a "shell" definition of the function on the local machine but that slows down the queries considerably as well.

Ultimately the goal is to separate out the "custom" piece of the data warehouse from the vendor supplied "application" data warehouse.  Currently it is (mostly) separate but still on the same server which is interfering with other clients since the custom warehouse uses a lot of resources.  The custom warehouse also needs access to other things like R and BI products so we thought a totally separate server would be a good choice.

Thoughts or suggestions?  I would be open to a totally different configuration or just technical SQL solutions.

Comment: Put the remote data that you need into local temporary tables.  Add the appropriate indexes and run the queries locally.